# According to which sections I should know that my file system is not in good condition in using the command dumpe2fs?

Tags: command-line, system-info

i wanted to know actually on what parameters should i look at in command dumpe2fs To know that my file system is in good or bad condition and how I solve the problem if my file system is in bad condition? .

Comment: What version of Ubuntu? Also is there an error you are getting?

Comment: Hey, it's not that the command is doing a problem the problem is that I do not understand which sections I should use that tell me that my file system is in bad condition and what can I do to fix it.
 The version is 20.10